# Same name for Laravel controller and model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I had a model `Entry` and had no problem with it.

After I created a new Controller with same name, the model stopped working.

When I execute `Enrty::where(...`  a Fatal error occurs:

```
Call to undefined method entry::where()
```

Comment: Rename the controller to `EntryController`.

Comment: If they're in the same namespace, then it's not going to work. You can try @WereWolf-TheAlpha's suggestion, or move the model or controller (or both) to a different namespace.

Comment: @Kryten I've tried namespaces from this tutorial  http://daylerees.com/codebright/controllers  but an error occurs `Class Blog\Controller\entry does not exist` I don't know why it doesn't find the class!

Comment: are you creating model and controller creating through artisan command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define Controller

```
<?php namespace Controllers;

class Entry extends \BaseController {}
```

Define Model

```
<?php namespace Models;

class Entry extends \Eloquent {}
```

Now, you can use these classes if you import/alias them

```
use Controllers\Entry as EntryController;
use Models\Entry as EntryModel;

EntryController::method();
EntryModel::anotherMethod();
```

**Note:** this code serves to show the principle.

Answer (score 1):

### without changing/renaming namespaces

simply use `as` keyword

```
use Models\Car as CarModel;
```